# How to reference an image from computer directory as a background image in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage in visual studio 2012 using HTML page. I want to upload an image from my computer directory. As currently m fetching it from URL.

Comment: Do you have any code or an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple.

Let's do it this way:

1. Create a folder called, say, - "myWebsite"
2. Inside 'myWebsite' folder put all your html files
3. Inside 'myWebsite' folder create another folder called 'images'
4. Inside 'images' put your image. let's name your image - sampleImage.jpg
5. Inside 'myWebsite' folder create another folder called 'css' and put your css file there

Now in your CSS file do this:

```
body{
    background-image:url('../images/sampleImage.jpg');
}
```

Try it and let me know if you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the image relative to your pages. For example, if your site is structured built in a folder called public_html and your page your image is to be located on is index.html and you've placed an image called example.jpg in a folder called img within public_html, you could reference that image from index.html with the following:

```
<img src="img/example.jpg" alt="" />
```

For security purposes, you can't reference local images, they need to be uploaded somewhere. Say you uploaded the image to the root of example.com you would change the src to "http://www.example.com/example.jpg"

Since you want it as your background image, you should use some css such as:

```
body {background:url('img/example.jpg') repeat;}
```